# What do we call a disconnected graph, with cycles

Tags: graph

I know that A forest is when they are disconnected, however with no cycles.
Graphs are connected, and may have a cycle.
However, I do not know what a disconnected graph, with cycles is called.

Comment: You can also try posting this question to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it [disjoint union of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_of_graphs) or simply [disconnected graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Connected_graph) (see also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisconnectedGraph.html)

There are also some subclasses:

> Certain special classes of graphs may be represented using disjoint
>   union operations. In particular:
>
> 1. The forests are the disjoint unions of trees.
> 2. The cluster graphs are the disjoint unions of complete graphs.
> 3. The 2-regular graphs are the disjoint unions of cycle graphs.
>
> More generally, every graph is the disjoint union of connected graphs,
>   its connected components.
>
> The cographs are the graphs that can be constructed from single-vertex
>   graphs by a combination of disjoint union and complement operations.

Couls also be:

> A [pseudoforest](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudoforest.html) is an undirected graph in which every connected component contains at most one graph cycle.